# Relation of Convex Polygons to Halin Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, plane-geometry, special-graphs

Can every [Halin graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halin_graph) be visualized as the union of a planar, strictly convex polygon with its Voronoi Diagram?

It is true, that every union of a strictly convex planar polygon with its Voronoi diagram corresponds to a Halin graph], but is the converse also true?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this paper answers your question definitively, but I believe
it directly addresses the topic, albeit in different language. "We prove there exists only a finite set of planar embeddings of a tree appearing as straight skeletons of convex polygons."

> Cheng, Howard, Satyan L. Devadoss, Brian Li, and Andrej Risteski. "Skeletal configurations of ribbon trees." *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 170 (2014): 46-54.
>   ([Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X14000171).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: MedialAxis]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.5a.</sup>

---

Comment: from  the abstract of the article I conclude that every Halin graph has such an embedding, but only finitely many different ones per graph; besides that, nothing seems to be indicated about whether among those polygons there will always be a convex one. So for the moment, I am a bit hesitant about accepting your answer.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: That's fine & appropriate. Note there is a distinction between realizing the combinatorial type of a particular tree, and realizing a particular geometric embedding, with edge lengths and/or angles prescribed. I presume you are only after the combinatorial type.

Comment: Yes, I am really only after the topological variant.